# Differentiate between local file or URI

Tags: ruby

I have an external library that needs to be instantiated differently depending on whether the parameter is a local file or an online file.

Right now I have this (I assume the file is always online):

```
def initialize(path)
  url_image = open(path)
  @image = Magick::ImageList.new
  @image.from_blob(url_image.read)
end
```

What would be the best way to differentiate if the file is locally stored? I have thought of doing this:

```
def initialize(path, is_online = true)
   if is_online
     url_image = open(path)
     @image = Magick::ImageList.new
     @image.from_blob(url_image.read)
   else
     @image = Magick::ImageList.new(path)
   end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a general rule if a URI has a host, it's not a local file.

```
require 'uri'
if URI(path).host.nil?
  #local
else 
  #external
end
```

Then your interface doesn't need to change.